# How to get value returned by Callback function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, return-value

Here is my piece of code am trying:

```
initData:function(period)
{    
    this.getLoadObject('0',url, this.callbackFunction);
},
```

I want to receive a return value from callBackFunction, which I want to be returned by `initData`.

Can any body help me, am not so proficient with JS.
I tried similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897748/return-value-from-callback-function) but didn't get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the callback function may very well be called asynchronously, that is after the return from the call to initData.

If it is synchronous however, you can do this:

```
initData:function(period)
            {   
                var that = this;
                var result;
                this.getLoadObject('0',url, function() {
                    result = that.callbackFunction(arguments));
                });
                return result;
            },
```

Comment: Pass a callback as an argument to initData

Answer (score 1):

Although it's impossible to tell from your code snippet, it looks like your callback function will be called asynchronously. if this is the case you will need to set variables that you want to be populated by initData within the callback function itself.

you could also wrap the callback function:

```
    var context = this;
    this.getLoadObject('0',url, function() {
       var returnedval = context.callbackFunction.apply(context,arguments);
       context.SomeFuctionToUseValue(returnedval);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use variable outside the function, so you can access it inside the callback function and outside.

```
var result = false;
initData:function(period)
{   
   this.getLoadObject('0',url, this.callbackFunction);
   //inside the callback you can modify the "result" then
   return result;
},
```