# Multiple get requests jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, get

I'm trying to read in several urls as text and store them into an array with jquery's ajax/get. I need to wait for all data to be obtained (and pushed to an array) and then return it in a function. From what I read online, this isn't possible.

I figured if I set a global array variable and pushed into that every time new data is obtained, then checked using a while loop if the array is saturated, when it is return. See below

You can assume all errors are handled within the `get` call

```
function fetchData(){
   x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
   a = [];

   //Loop, get and push data
   $.each(x, function( i, val ) {
       $.get("http://someurl/"+i, function( data ) {
           a.push(data);
       });
   });

   // Wait till our array is populated?
   while(a.length < x.length){
       console.log(a.length);
   }
   return a;
}
```

However, this approach does not seem to be working and nothing is ever added to the array.. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: trying to return a value from a async function is a very bad idea... instead why don't make use a callback mechanism

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897748/return-value-from-callback-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) and [Javascript callback for multiple ajax calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/javascript-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is to use a callback

```
function fetchData(callback) {
    var requests = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        requests.push($.get("http://someurl/" + i))
    }

    $.when.apply($, requests).then(function () {
        var array = $.map(arguments, function (arg) {
            return arg[0];
        });
        callback(array);
    })
}

fetchData(function (array) {
    //do something with array
})
```

PoC: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CmsKk/)

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing with the second half part where you call `args[0]` I'm not getting the expected results.

Comment: the `then` callback will get an array of parameters which are the arguments of each of the target ajax calls... so each of those has 3 items the data, status and ajax request from which we need to fetch only the data which is `data[0]`

Answer (score 2):

#### issue 1

Here you are doing `console.log` on the result array even before the callbacks get fired. So the array `a` will always be empty. What you want to do is to trigger the `console.log` after all the values in array `x` are processed.

#### issue 2

You are trying to return the result array back. Instead you should try getting the code that processes `a` inside the callback.

like

```
function fetchData(cb){
   x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
   a = [];

   //Loop, get and push data
   $.each(x, function( i, val ) {
       $.get("http://someurl/"+i, function( data ) {
           a.push(data);
           
           if(a.length == x.length) {
                //looping logic taken inside callback
                while(a.length < x.length){
                   console.log(a.length);
                   
               }
               //calling the callback on result
               cb(a);
           }
           
       });
   });  
   
}

fetchData(function(data){

    //process a here

});
```

Comment: Beware! The order which `a` is populated is most likely not in `x` order.

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can't make sure ajax calls will be done synchronously. To do so you can do a normal ajax call or you can use [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

In those ways you can make sure array will be read after all calls been processed. You better to have a timeout too, because some call may not return in time.